# Which congressional districts were won by over 40 points by either party in the 2016 presidential election?

Tags: united-states, election, congress, presidential-election, data-sources

I am curious about congressional districts in the 2016 election, and I want to know which ones were won by Clinton or Trump by over 40 points. I am doing this to analyze the difference in margin of victory in House and presidential races. Can you name the districts for Clinton and Trump in separate lists?

Note: I want >40 pp because this gives me a pure(r) sample of each party's voters, and it gets rid of the likelihood of having a split district. I collected a few, but I want to see them all. I had an easier time finding Clinton districts than Trump districts, but I could find both types of CDs.

Comment: both parties try to avoid such over-kill where possible, as anything above PVI of 10 is a waste of votes.

Answer (score 4):

Most publicly available datasets on presidential returns are by state, not congressional district. [This dataset from Princeton](https://dss.princeton.edu/studies/982) is by congressional district, but access does not appear to be free. [This map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2016_presidential_election,_results_by_congressional_district_(popular_vote_margin).svg) is the closest thing I've found accessible so far.

Answer (score 2):

Using data from [the Daily Kos](https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2012/11/19/1163009/-Daily-Kos-Elections-presidential-results-by-congressional-district-for-the-2012-2008-elections), specifically [this dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VfkHtzBTP5gf4jAu8tcVQgsBJ1IDvXEHjuMqYlOgYbA/edit#gid=0) which uses the 2016 congressional district boundaries, we can see that 108 of the 435 districts were won by a margin of 40% or more. 75 of these were won by Clinton, with the remaining 33 won by Trump. Full CSV data separated out by winner is below. From this, I've created the below map showing Trump districts in red, and Clinton districts in blue.

[image]

You may also find the below image from Wikipedia useful - this also uses the linked dataset.

[image]

<sub>[Mr.Election & Ali Zifan](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2016_presidential_election,_results_by_congressional_district_(popular_vote_margin).svg) / [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)</sub>

Clinton districts:

```
CD,Incumbent,Party,Clinton,Trump,Difference
NY-15,"Serrano, Jose",(D),93.8,4.9,88.9
NY-13,"Espaillat, Adriano",(D),92.3,5.4,86.9
PA-02,"Evans, Dwight",(D),90.4,7.6,82.8
CA-13,"Lee, Barbara",(D),87.4,6.8,80.6
IL-07,"Davis, Danny",(D),87.4,9.2,78.2
CA-12,"Pelosi, Nancy",(D),86.2,8.7,77.5
NY-07,"Velazquez, Nydia",(D),86.9,10.4,76.5
CA-37,"Bass, Karen",(D),85.7,9.6,76.1
GA-05,"Lewis, John",(D),85.0,11.9,73.1
NY-05,"Meeks, Gregory",(D),85.7,12.7,73
CA-34,"Gomez, Jimmy",(D),83.6,10.7,72.9
NJ-10,"Payne, Donald",(D),85.2,12.8,72.4
MA-07,"Capuano, Mike",(D),84.1,11.9,72.2
NY-08,"Jeffries, Hakeem",(D),84.6,13.5,71.1
CA-44,"Barragan, Nanette",(D),83.0,12.3,70.7
WA-07,"Jayapal, Pramila",(D),82.1,12.2,69.9
NY-12,"Maloney, Carolyn",(D),83.3,13.5,69.8
CA-40,"Roybal-Allard, Lucille",(D),82.2,12.8,69.4
NY-09,"Clarke, Yvette",(D),83.5,14.4,69.1
IL-04,"Gutierrez, Luis",(D),82.1,13.2,68.9
FL-24,"Wilson, Frederica",(D),82.9,15.4,67.5
OH-11,"Fudge, Marcia",(D),80.5,17.0,63.5
FL-20,"Hastings, Alcee",(D),80.2,18.1,62.1
CA-43,"Waters, Maxine",(D),78.4,16.7,61.7
PA-01,"Brady, Bob",(D),79.5,18.2,61.3
TX-09,"Green, Al",(D),79.3,18.0,61.3
CA-29,"Cardenas, Tony",(D),77.7,16.8,60.9
MI-14,"Lawrence, Brenda",(D),79.2,18.3,60.9
TX-30,"Johnson, E.B.",(D),79.1,18.3,60.8
MI-13,"Conyers, John",(D),78.8,18.1,60.7
NY-10,"Nadler, Jerrold",(D),78.3,18.8,59.5
IL-02,"Kelly, Robin",(D),78.0,19.1,58.9
CA-14,"Speier, Jackie",(D),76.9,18.2,58.7
MO-01,"Clay, Lacy",(D),77.0,18.8,58.2
NY-14,"Crowley, Joe",(D),77.7,19.8,57.9
TN-09,"Cohen, Steve",(D),77.5,19.8,57.7
MD-04,"Brown, Anthony",(D),77.2,19.7,57.5
TX-18,"Jackson-Lee, Sheila",(D),76.5,20.0,56.5
MD-07,"Cummings, Elijah",(D),75.8,20.2,55.6
MN-05,"Ellison, Keith",(D),73.7,18.5,55.2
NJ-08,"Sires, Albio",(D),75.7,21.5,54.2
IL-01,"Rush, Bobby",(D),75.4,21.4,54
CA-17,"Khanna, Ro",(D),73.9,20.5,53.4
CA-18,"Eshoo, Anna",(D),73.4,20.2,53.2
GA-04,"Johnson, Hank",(D),75.3,22.2,53.1
VA-08,"Beyer, Don",(D),73.5,20.9,52.6
NY-16,"Engel, Eliot",(D),75.1,22.5,52.6
LA-02,"Richmond, Cedric",(D),74.6,22.2,52.4
WI-04,"Moore, Gwen",(D),74.0,21.8,52.2
CA-19,"Lofgren, Zoe",(D),72.9,21.5,51.4
CA-28,"Schiff, Adam",(D),72.1,22.3,49.8
TX-33,"Veasey, Marc",(D),72.9,23.7,49.2
AZ-07,"Gallego, Ruben",(D),71.8,22.6,49.2
CA-51,"Vargas, Juan",(D),71.8,22.8,49
CA-11,"DeSaulnier, Mark",(D),71.5,22.7,48.8
OR-03,"Blumenauer, Earl",(D),70.7,22.5,48.2
CA-20,"Panetta, Jimmy",(D),70.4,23.2,47.2
WA-09,"Smith, Adam",(D),70.5,23.3,47.2
IL-05,"Quigley, Mike",(D),70.5,23.9,46.6
CO-01,"DeGette, Diana",(D),69.0,23.2,45.8
CA-02,"Huffman, Jared",(D),69.0,23.3,45.7
CA-15,"Swalwell, Eric",(D),69.9,24.2,45.7
TX-29,"Green, Gene",(D),71.1,25.4,45.7
IL-09,"Schakowsky, Jan",(D),70.1,24.9,45.2
CA-05,"Thompson, Mike",(D),69.2,24.3,44.9
CA-06,"Matsui, Doris",(D),69.2,24.4,44.8
GA-13,"Scott, David",(D),71.0,26.6,44.4
MA-05,"Clark, Katherine",(D),69.3,25.7,43.6
CA-30,"Sherman, Brad",(D),69.1,25.7,43.4
CA-33,"Lieu, Ted",(D),67.8,26.5,41.3
AL-07,"Sewell, Terri",(D),69.8,28.6,41.2
CA-35,"Torres, Norma",(D),67.7,26.9,40.8
TX-16,"O'Rourke, Beto",(D),67.9,27.2,40.7
NC-12,"Adams, Alma",(D),68.4,28.4,40
NC-04,"Price, David",(D),68.2,28.2,40
```

Trump Districts:

```
CD,Incumbent,Party,Clinton,Trump,Difference
AL-04,"Aderholt, Rob",(R),17.4,80.4,63
TX-13,"Thornberry, Mac",(R),16.9,79.9,63
KY-05,"Rogers, Hal",(R),17.5,79.6,62.1
TX-11,"Conaway, Michael",(R),19.1,77.8,58.7
GA-09,"Collins, Doug",(R),19.3,77.8,58.5
TN-01,"Roe, Phil",(R),19.7,76.7,57
NE-03,"Smith, Adrian",(R),20.0,74.9,54.9
MO-08,"Smith, Jason",(R),21.0,75.4,54.4
TX-04,"Ratcliffe, John",(R),21.8,75.4,53.6
GA-14,"Graves, Tom",(R),22.1,75.0,52.9
OK-03,"Lucas, Frank",(R),20.9,73.6,52.7
OK-02,"Mullin, Markwayne",(R),22.8,72.9,50.1
WV-03,"Jenkins, Evan",(R),23.3,72.5,49.2
TX-19,"Arrington, Jodey",(R),23.5,72.5,49
TN-06,"Black, Diane",(R),23.7,72.6,48.9
TX-08,"Brady, Kevin",(R),23.9,72.7,48.8
KY-01,"Comer, James",(R),23.9,72.4,48.5
WY-AL,"Cheney, Liz",(R),22.5,70.1,47.6
TX-01,"Gohmert, Louie",(R),25.3,72.2,46.9
TX-36,"Babin, Brian",(R),25.2,72.0,46.8
IL-15,"Shimkus, John",(R),24.5,70.7,46.2
MO-07,"Long, Billy",(R),24.7,70.4,45.7
KS-01,"Marshall, Roger",(R),24.3,69.3,45
AL-06,"Palmer, Gary",(R),26.1,70.8,44.7
OH-06,"Johnson, Bill",(R),26.7,69.3,42.6
PA-09,"Schuster, Bill",(R),27.2,69.7,42.5
LA-01,"Scalise, Steve",(R),26.7,68.7,42
WV-01,"McKinley, David",(R),26.4,68.0,41.6
VA-09,"Griffith, Morgan",(R),27.3,68.8,41.5
MS-04,"Palazzo, Steven",(R),28.2,69.4,41.2
TN-04,"DesJarlais, Scott",(R),27.4,68.6,41.2
IN-06,"Messer, Luke",(R),27.4,67.7,40.3
AZ-04,"Gosar, Paul",(R),27.5,67.7,40.2
```